# "FatalExecutionEngineError was detected" when using Console.Writeline after redefining String.Empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clr

I'm trying (for fun) to redefine `String.Empty` to be a single space "". Why does this break the CLR framework?

Message:

> The runtime has encountered a
>   fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x5814b976, on thread 0xf40.
>   The error code is 0x80131623. This
>   error may be a bug in the CLR or in
>   the unsafe or non-verifiable portions
>   of user code. Common sources of this
>   bug include user marshaling errors for
>   COM-interop or PInvoke, which may
>   corrupt the stack.

How to reproduce:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        typeof(string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, " ");
        Console.WriteLine("{}", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very sure .. but don't you need `{0}` there ? and also specify `string.Empty`

Comment: @V4Vandetta is right, putting {0} fixes the issues. But that's a weird error message anyhow.

Comment: Try this code : 
 typeof (string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, "Test");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Empty);
You Get : TestTest, it seems that the frameworks adds an extra String.Empty at the beginning of every String.

Comment: Think they use it as the dummy in "null object patern" implmentation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Therefore it isn't strange its added to the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{}", "");
    }
}
```

then it will fail with an `FormatException` with the error message `Input string was not in a correct format`.

However when we insert `typeof(string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, " ");` before the line with `Console.WriteLine` then the code fails when it tries to look up that error message. If we look at the full stacktrace (including "Show external code") then we see that the code fails at `System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(string fileName = " mscorlib.resources")` (notice the space in front of mscorlib.resources).

The reason for this is that `ManifestBasedResourceGroveler` uses the metode `GetResourceFileName` of `ResourceManager` to find the resource file. And in `GetResourceFileName` we use a `StringBuilder` to construct the filename and the constructor of `StringBuilder` starts with `String.Empty`.

```
public StringBuilder(int capacity)
    : this(String.Empty,capacity){
}
```